# Firebase Database Complex Querying Returning Incorrect Result

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebaseui

I have a Firebase Database that essentially looks like the following:

[image]

Ultimately, I am trying to capture "Trending" information. "Trending" would constitute:

1. Recent (When it was added to Firebase)
2. Highly Regarded (Highest Vote Count)

I am using the FirebaseUI (latest version 3.0.1) with my database. I have my query as the following:

```
    Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference()
            .child("Polls")
            .limitToLast(3)
            .orderByChild("vote_count");

       FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Poll> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Poll>()
            .setQuery(query, Poll.class)
            .build();


    mFireAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Poll, PollHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(final PollHolder holder, int position, Poll model) {
                holder.mPollQuestion.setText(model.getQuestion());
                String voteCount = String.valueOf(model.getVote_count());

            //TODO: Investigate formatting of vote count for thousands
            holder.mVoteCount.setText(voteCount);
            Picasso.with(getActivity().getApplicationContext())
                    .load(model.getImage_URL())
                    .fit()
                    .into(holder.mPollImage);
            holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent toClickedPoll = new Intent(getActivity(), PollHostActivity.class);
                    toClickedPoll.putExtra("POLL_ID", mFireAdapter.getRef(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getKey());
                    startActivity(toClickedPoll);

                }
            });
        }


   @Override
        public PollHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.latest_item,parent,false);
            return new PollHolder(v);
        }
    };
```

The hope is to first see the most recently added children, and then order those children by the vote_count child. Unfortunately, this query is not handling correctly, as it is ordering by child first and THEN limiting to 3.

Is my query possible? Would an update to the Cloud Firestore resolve?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this, you need to use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query query = rootRef.child("Polls").orderByChild("vote_count").limitToLast(3);
query.addValueEventListener(/* ... */);
```

Comment: So I need to add the valueeventlistener before using the query in the recyclerview?

Comment: No, it was only as an example. Does that query work?

Comment: I believe your query is the same as mine?

Comment: Thanks I will give it a shot, I first want to limit and then sort by child. Appreciate your help. Happy Thanskgiving!

Comment: You too! Keep me posted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159714/discussion-between-alex-mamo-and-tccpg288).

Comment: No, it simply is not performing the query the way I had hoped. Firebase has suggested changing it client-side, I am a bit confused how I would go about doing that. https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/1040

Comment: Add a screenshot of your code, to see more exactly.

Comment: What specific code would you want to see that is not above? I am trying to figure out how I would sort by the child on the client side

Comment: I have added the rest of my recyclerview code, appreciate the help.

Comment: I have not, and Firebase has basically stated it is not possible unless I handle it on the client side, which could involve modifying the FirebaseUI adapter or even creating a customer adapter. I am still trying to accomplish, any help, thoughts would be appreciated:https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/1040

Answer (score 1):

Add`orderByChild("vote_count")`before `limitToLast(3)` becauase to solve your current situation, you need to first sort the points i.e. {1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 10, 15} then pic the last 3 points {6, 10, 15}.

Like this

```
    Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference()
                .child("Polls")
                .orderByChild("vote_count")
                .limitToLast(3);
```

Comment: I tried this, and it still is not working, imagine I have "First: 3, Second: 1, Third: 5." I then add "Fourth," which means "Fourth" becomes the most recent. It should automatically bump off "First," regardless of the fact that "First" has a higher value than "Second." If limiting to last 3, "First" should be out as it is not one of the last 3.